# Angular UI-Router redirect route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The Angular UI-Router documentation uses the following example for redirecting:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when(state.url, ['$match', '$stateParams', function ($match, $stateParams) {
    if ($state.$current.navigable != state || !equalForKeys($match, $stateParams)) {
        $state.transitionTo(state, $match, false);
    }
}]);
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#when-for-redirection

My question is about `state.url`. You can get a state's url by using the `$state` service, e.g. `$state.get('home')`

But this is a service and is not available in the config phase, so how would I go about obtaining a states url to put it as the first parameter of `$urlRouterProvider.when`?

Answer (score 0):

`$routeProvider` is a shim the implements the current AngularJS `$route / $routeProvider` API on top of `$stateProvider`, to make it easier for people to transition applications to $`stateProvider` step by step -- it simply fudges the route definition into a state definition by making up a name, and some other small things.

`$urlRouterProvider` simply has the responsibility of watching `$location`, and when it changes running through a list of rules one by one until one matches. How exactly "matching" is defined and what happens when a rule matches is up to that rule; at the lowest level its just a function that returns true if it has handled the URL. However there is support built on top of this for rules that are `RegExps`, as well as path patterns with placeholders (as used by state.url) that are compiled into rules via `$urlMatcherFactory`. `$urlRouterProvider` also supports redirects.

As it stands `$urlRouterProvider` should already be faster than the corresponding code in `$routeProvider`, because it doesn't re-parse url patterns on every location change, but instead hangs on to the compiled `UrlMatcher` objects.

Comment: Great, thanks for this information. So, for handling redirects, would you recommend using creating a custom regex matcher (and corresponding this to the states url)?

Comment: Yeah. Creating your own custom Regex matcher should solve the purpose

Comment: Right ok, this seems a little redundant, but if there is no other solution then this will work.

Answer (score 0):

This actually works nicer, because you don't have to create a regex:

```
var forks = {
  issueConditionFork: function() {
    if ($stateParams.serviceType === 'sell') {
      return 'condition';
    }
  }
};

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, state) {
  var fork;
  fork = forks[state.name];
  if (fork) {
    $state.go(fork());
    return event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

In your run block.